# ASP.Net textbox should not suggest old values

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want my textbox to NOT suggest the old values (when clicked) entered in it before.

Comment: Good for you. Did you have a question?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Your browser is remembering the values. you can use autocomplete="off" attribute. If that is your question...

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are asking... But maybe searching for "disable autocomplete IE" will give an answer.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry I forgot the question. But thank you for the solutions.

Comment: You can enable/disable viewstate using the property of the control (EnableViewState) or even at page level. EnableViewState is enabled by default on TextBoxes. If it is turned on, then it WILL keep your values between postbacks.

Comment: I also tried your answer sir. It also works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `autocomplete` attribute in your html element to `false`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" autocomplete="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can also do it for your entire form:

```
<form id="myForm" autocomplete="off" method="post" runat="server">
```

Comment: Totally works. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: For me this did not work, I had to change it to: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" autocomplete="off" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 2):

You can set its [AutoCompleteType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) property to `Disabled`.

```
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1"
    autocompletetype="Disabled" 
    runat="server"/>
```